# Ошибка запуска grequests

Tags: python

Не запускается скрипт с использованием библиотеки grequests, не могу понять с чем это связано, прошу помочь.

При этом обычный requests работает.

Код:

```
import grequests
import config

grequests.get(f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{config.api_token}/sendMessage?',
            params={
                'chat_id': 1063622720,
                'text': (f"\nТвой кошелек:")
            })
```

Ошибка:

```
C:\Users\musix\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\grequests.py:22: MonkeyPatchWarning: Monkey-patching ssl after ssl has already been imported may lead to errors, including RecursionError on Python 3.6. It may also silently lead to incorrect behaviour on Python 3.7. Please monkey-patch earlier. See https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/1016. 
Modules that had direct imports (NOT patched): ['urllib3.util (C:\\Users\\musix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\urllib3\\util\\__init__.py)', 'urllib3.util.ssl_ (C:\\Users\\musix\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\urllib3\\util\\ssl_.py)']. 
  curious_george.patch_all(thread=False, select=False)
```

Comment: `Please monkey-patch earlier. See https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/1016`, смотрели в той ссылке решение?

Comment: @gil9red, Да оно мне не помогло